# Use of instrumental with был/быть, e.g. "Ты был забавным."

Tags: грамматика, творительный-падеж, essive, изобразительный-падеж

Today the following sentence came up in a chat with a Russian friend:

Ты был забавным.

Here the adjective is in <strike>dative</strike> instrumental case, but I would expect it to be in nominative together with the verb был/быть.

When I asked my friend why she didn't write Ты был забавный, she explained that this was because it was in past tense. But I cannot find this rule anywhere in Russian grammar books.

Can anybody explain the use of <strike>dative</strike> instumental in this sentence?

Edit: I mistakenly wrote dative case above. I meant instrumental case.

Comment: The case is _instrumental_ here.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/8359/2104

Comment: Similar question: https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/15702/2104

Comment: And one more: https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/14134/2104

Comment: an [explanation](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/14136/7674) by reference to [Essive case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essive_case) is particularly noteworthy

Comment: Sergey, thank you for your edits. Yes, this is instrumental, not dative. I was mistaken.

Comment: Here’s a well-known song almost entirely made out of this kind of construct: http://mp3s.cc/song/splin_prihodi/

Comment: another similar question [Быть с именительным падежом](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/10610/Быть-с-именительным-падежом)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The noun and adjective functioning as the nominal part of a compound predicate can be in the *nominative* **or** in the *instrumental* case.
Typically, the nominative here [where the linking verb *быть* is present] corresponds to a *permanent* quality of the subject while the instrumental case better combines with a *temporary* quality.

In much more detail (Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.CПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ, M.: ЧеРо, 1999):
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/62.htm#%D0%B7_02

(see §179. Формы сказуемого)

Answer (score 3):

What can be added to the answers in the past topics referenced by Sergey Slepov in the comments, is that at least in your example, usage of adjective in nominal or instrumental affects semantics of the phrase.

***Ты был забавный*** <sup>*Nom.*</sup> would relegate your being ***забавный*** to a distant past, when there was *another you* so to speak, for example in the childhood, youth etc, that is once you were so. That's probably agrees with the fact of it indicating *permanent* (or stable within certain time limits) quality as mentioned elsewhere.

***Ты был забавным*** <sup>*Instr.*</sup> can be applied to any time span.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and reference to the previous topic on essive. Yes, this is instrumental case, I was mistaken when I wrote dative case originally.

Comment: @joshualotz sure, no prob, mistakes are welcome

Comment: @joshualotz I too was very surprised when I first met this construction since it was not taught in any course or textbook I had as a student. It applies to the *future* tense as much as the past (just not the present), e.g., когда я был студентом... and когда я буду аспирантом...