# Which cases are used with быть

Tags: грамматика, падежи, genitive-negative, творительный-падеж

I believe that the phrases in Russian for 'I was a student' is Я был студентом (instrumental case) and 'I was not a student' is Я не было студента (genitive case) and 'I am a student' is Я студент (nominative case) and 'I am not a student' is Я не студента (genitive case). Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The negative statements are off.

**Я не был студентом** - Instrumental just like in the positive statement.

**Я не студент** - Nominative just like in the positive statement.

*Genitive negative* is only applicable in cases where what's described is not an attribute inherent to the noun or actions performed by it but eventivity associated with it or to which it's subjected (which is why *Genitive negative* sounds like a passive voice).

***Я не был студентом***, BUT ***Меня не было дома***

> **Я не был** студентом, поэтому **меня не было** в списках учащихся. - I wasn't a student so i wasn't found in the registers.
>
> **Они** здесь **не бывают** - **They don't** stop by here
>   **Их** здесь **не бывает** - **They're not** found here

The verb **быть** has 2 meanings: **to be** (inherent attribute) and **to be present / to obtain** (eventivity). In the Present tense, where it's not explicitly used, an inherent state (which in negation requires Nominative) is negated with the particle **не** while eventivity (which in negation requires Genitive) is negated with the particle **нет/у**

**`Я не`** **студент** BUT **`Меня`** **здесь** **`нет`** / **У меня** **`его нет/у`**

To put it differently, the semantics of *Genitive negative* with the verb **быть** in particular is not simply that *something is/was not* but that *something is/was not relative to other circumstances*.

Answer (score 2):

In the construction

> *X* **was**/**were**/**will be** *somebody*/*something*

*somebody*/*something* should be in the **Instrumental case** irrespective of whether it is affirmative or negative:

> Я был студент**ом** — Я *не* был студент**ом**
>
> Мы были студент**ами** — Мы *не* были студент**ами**
>
> Вы будете студент**ами** — Вы *не* будете студент**ами**

The **Genitive case** is used after **быть** iт the following **negative** construction:

> [somewhere] **there** **wasn't**/**weren't**/**won't be** *somebody*/*something*

For example:

> Там не было это**го** студент**а**
>
> Летом здесь не будет студент**ов**

Comment: Thank you. However I still can't understand in the positive statements 'I am a student' and 'I was a student' how the first is nominative я студент and the second is instrumental я Был студентом

Comment: @Bob Daley please refer to the discussion [Use of instrumental with был/быть](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/16379/use-of-instrumental-with-был-быть-e-g-Ты-был-забавным) and through links posted there to other discussions of this topic. To the present tense Instrumental can be applicable as well if you use a verb, e.g. **Я являюсь студентом**

Comment: @BobDaley - _Я студент_ has **no** verb, so you use the Nominative case. There's nothing to understand, just remember that as a rule.

Answer (score 0):

In Russian language, we skip "to be" in the present tense. I am a student. Я студент. But in past and future we use it.